# VSTS PowerShell Task and Azure AD cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to run a PowerShell script during deployment using a PowerShell Script Task in VSTS release. I need to do some operation with Azure Active Directory, but right now I have no access to it, although running locally works fine.

For example running Get-AzureRmADApplication gives "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".

Any solutions or suggestions to this issue?

P. S. Actually I was using Azure PowerShell task.

Comment: I submit a feedback (updated in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue, there is a similar issue: [New-AzureRmADApplication: Access denied to the specified API version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1896)

I submit a new issue [Get-AzureRmADApplication Access denied to the specified API version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3686), you can follow up it.

Answer (score 0):

When running commands against Azure Active Directory you will have to give the application it is running under Read Directory rights in Azure Active Directory.